# converting string into date format with Python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, type-conversion

Hi I am trying to convert this string in Python : '2019-01-10' into date format as 2019-01-10

I have tried this code :

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = '2019-01-10'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%y-%m-%d )
```

but i have a ValueError : time data '2019-01-10' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

`%y` format specifier is 2 digits, use uppercase `%Y`. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '2018-06-29'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

try changing it to the above code.